# numpy.unique sort based on counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numpy, unique

The `numpy.unique` function allows to return the counts of unique elements if `return_counts` is `True`. Now the returned tuple consists of two arrays one containing the unique elements and the 2nd one containing a count array, both are sorted by the unique elements. Now is there a way to have both sorted according to the counts array instead of the unique elements? I mean I know how to do it the hard way but is there some concise one-liner or lambda functionality for such cases?

Current result:

```
my_chr_list = ["a","a","a", "b", "c", "b","d", "d"]
unique_els, counts = np.unique(my_chr_list, return_counts=True)
print(unique_els, counts)
```

Which returns something along the lines of this:

```
>>> (array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
     dtype='<U1'), array([3, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

However, what I would want to have:

```
>>> (array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'], 
     dtype='<U1'), array([3, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't do this directly with `unique` function. Instead as a Numpythonic approach, you can use  `return_index` keyword to get the indices of the unique items then use `np.argsort` to get the indices of the sorted `count` items and use the result to find the items based on their frequency.

```
In [33]: arr = np.array(my_chr_list)

In [34]: u, count = np.unique(my_chr_list, return_counts=True)

In [35]: count_sort_ind = np.argsort(-count)

In [36]: u[count_sort_ind]
Out[36]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [37]: count[count_sort_ind]
Out[37]: array([3, 2, 2, 1])
```

Comment: I believe `-count` in `np.argsort(-count)` is to return indices of the reversed sorted array. I didn't quite find this instruction in the numpy documentation; is it a general rule of thumb that indexing a list-like datastructure with a negative number tends to reverse the returned order? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SumanthLazarus No, that's not mentioned in documentation explicitly. It all depends on the way the sorting functions work. i.e. the way they sort a given iterable (descending or ascending) which using the negation you can just reverse the sorting order.